# Implement UI-GRID angular on spring mvc view

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm trying to implement UI-GRID for the very fisrt time but having some problems on it, I've seen some basic tutorials to implement it but I can get to do it, I'm using an HTML file as view (also using Thymeleaf, JS and jQuery), on Spring mvc,

would be good if you could help me on an step by step guide, thanks